# Product of polynomials with exponents from a given set

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $k$ be a field and let $S\subset \mathbb N$ be an infinite subset. Let
$f\in k[t]$ be a polynomial. Show that there exists a polynomial $g \in k[t]$
such that
$$f(t)g(t) =\sum _{i\ge 0} a_i t^i$$
where $a_i = 0$ for every $i \not\in S$.

I have solved for the case when the complement of $S$ is finite.
If $S^c$ is finite then we can just take $g(t)=t^N$, where $N=1+\max(S^c)$.

Comment: Would you present your solution for the cases You mention?

Comment: This is duplicate but I can't find it right now

Comment: In this formulation of the problem $g\equiv 0$ would do

Comment: @PeterMelech I have added a solution for one of the cases. Also, yes, I think you would need to find a non-zero polynomial.